# FFMPEG - Youtube MP4 video stream loop?

Tags: ffmpeg

its my first post on this community.

Im from brazil, so im sorry for bad english.

I am using FFMPEG on Ubuntu VPS for streaming 24/7 mp4 video on youtube.

I am using this code:

```
VBR="2500k"                                    
FPS="30"                                    
QUAL="veryfast"                              
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"

SOURCE="/stream/video.mp4"           
KEY="my_Secret_key"                               

ffmpeg \
    -i "$SOURCE" -deinterlace \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

With this code, i have sucesfully put my stream online, but i need that the code loop and repeat the mp4 file, because i dont want to make a 24h mp4 file.

How can i make that this mp4 file (SOURCE="/stream/video.mp4") repeat itself infinitely?

I dont have imagens and notthing, i only put a mp4 file on stream!

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve this by prepending the source with stream_loop parameter and -1 value specifying indefinite looping.

Replace

```
-i "$SOURCE" -deinterlace \
```

with

```
-stream_loop -1 -i "$SOURCE" -deinterlace \
```

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options